# Options on List Element Android vs. iOS

Tags: android, ios, human-interface-guideline, standards

I am designing a mobile app. One of the screens contains a list. There are options for each list element such as `view details`, `edit`, `delete`, ...

For Android there is the `more options` icon (three vertical dots) that I can put on each list element. Tapping on the icon would open a little context menu with a list of options.

What is the appropriate way to implement list element options in iOS?

Tapping the list element itself is already occupied with our primary use case (mark/flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many iOS application use 3 horizontal dots on the top right to indicate more options.

Read this: 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/

Comment: Thanks! Just for the records: The Apple Music App is an example where 3 horizontal dots trigger an Action Sheet. http://www.iphonehacks.com/2015/07/how-to-use-up-next-feature-in-new-music-app.html